# Accept and change

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any word which accumulates the meaning of both words "Accept" and "Change"?

Example : I accepted and changed myself from the feedback given.

Comment: If the feedback caused you to change, then it seems like the "accept" part is already implied. Had you rejected the feedback, you would not have changed.

Comment: I changed myself in spite of my loathing of the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To conform  may convey the idea ,  (though a bit formal) :

> - (usually foll by: to) to comply in actions, behaviour, etc, with accepted standards or norms

Source:http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Conform

Or, To attune:

> - to bring into accord, harmony, or sympathetic relationship; adjust: to attune oneself to country living.
> - to tune or bring into harmony.

Source:http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Attune

Comment: Thanks, Attune was the word I was looking for. My example and question was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your example sentence means that you accepted yourself... "from" the feedback given. Which means you were that feedback before. I think you mean you accepted the feedback, and changed yourself based on it.

It won't be easy to put that into one verb, but maybe something like:

> I took the feedback on board.

Conveys what you want. It means that you took the feedback in and you imply that you did something with it (whether that includes changing yourself depends on the feedback!)

At first I was thinking in an IT-context, where you can accept settings and change a program's behaviour based on that. A much-used verb is then **apply**. Actually you could also say you *applied* (the points made in) the feedback to yourself, meaning that you put into effect the actions or changes that the feedback includes. That implies that you accepted the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I like

> I [complied](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/compliance) with the suggestions

Source:http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/compliance

Answer (score 0):

*Adapt* can be used as an alternative.

**Example**: He needed to adapt his strategies when dealing with her.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Adapt